# DryIoc in XamarinAndroid Register Singleton is working but normal Register doesn't working

Tags: xamarin.android, dryioc

I have a MyGameView class inherits from IMyGameView interface and AndroidGameView class from OpenTK.

So, if i register MyGameView class with singleton it is working but if i register as normal registration, application doesn't answer and output text is meaningless.

Class and interface:

```
public class MyGameView : AndroidGameView, IMyGameView
{
    public MyGameView(Context context, ISurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) : base(context)
    {

    }
}

public interface IMyGameView
{

}
```

`Container.Register< IMyGameView, MyGameView> (Reuse.Singleton);` **working**

`Container.Register< IMyGameView, MyGameView>();` **not working**

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it.

It needs to setup line for allow disposable on register.

```
setup: setup.Setup(allowTransientDisposable: true)
```

In my code it will be like that:

```
Container.Register< IMyGameView,MyGameView>(setup:setup.Setup(allowTransientDisposable: true));
```

But why i didn't see the error from `DryIoc` container? Because `xamarin` optimize c# code option was open. This kept the exception from me and i didn't see the error.